# How to show a random number between values daily

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to generate/store/show a number between 10-45 to all visitors, changing daily.

I have it working weekly (I think).

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

     var minNumber = 10;
     var maxNumber = 45;


     if (!localStorage.getItem("responsetime") && !localStorage.getItem("responsetime") ) {

         var d = Date.now();
         var RandomNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*(maxNumber-minNumber+1))+minNumber);

         localStorage.setItem("responsetime",RandomNum);
         localStorage.setItem("myTime",d);

     }


     else {

         var newTime = Date.now();
         var oldTime = localStorage.getItem("responsetime");

         if(newTime - oldTime > 7*24*60*60*1000) { 

             RandomNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*(maxNumber-minNumber+1))+minNumber);
             localStorage.setItem("responsetime",RandomNum);
             localStorage.setItem("myTime",newTime);

         }

     }

     $(".responsetime").text(localStorage.getItem("responsetime"))

 })
```

I expect the out of 10-45, stored in local storage and change daily for all visitors.

Comment: What is your problem and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Local storage is per user / browser. If you'd like all users to see the same value, you'd need to either set that value on a server, or make it deterministic (e.g. pseudo random based on the date).

Comment: How can I set the value on the server?